# Printing a random csv cell with string and inserted variable in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am a python noob, so please take it easy on me.

I have an example csv file (actual csv file has 20 rows and 2 columns similar to what is shown below):

```
"I hate %s" % x, "I am a %s" % x
"I heart %s" % x, "I am not a %s" % x
```

My python 2.7 script:

```
from csv import *

x = "gorillas"

with open('csv_test.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    spamreader = reader(csvfile, quoting = QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    list = []
    for row in spamreader:
        list.append(row[0])

    print list[1]   

csvfile.close()
```

I would like my script to print:

```
I heart gorillas
```

instead it is printing:

```
"I heart %s" % x
```

So, my variable, x, is not being inserted into my string. I assume that my problem is that when I pull the contents of the cell from my csv, the whole cell content is considered a string. However, I do not know how to fix this issue.

As a bonus or follow-up, I would also like to be selecting a random cell from my csv file.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to let the csv file be interpreted as a string format code line.
That would require you to interpret the string as a part of the script.
You can do this with *eval()*

```
print eval(list[1])
```

ought to do it.

Depending on you application, eval can be useful, but generally I would **not** recommend reading an input from somewhere, and then run the contents using eval.
consider the thought experiment where the text is posted by a user on a website.
If the post contains valid python code, they have just gained access to running their own scripts on your machine.

Instead, you could replace parts of the string.
and then loose the '% x' format specifier

```
from csv import *

x = "gorillas"

with open('csv_test.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    spamreader = reader(csvfile, quoting = QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    list = []
    for row in spamreader:
        list.append(row[0])

    print list[1].replace("%s", x)   

csvfile.close()
```

Comment: I see from all the answers that one solution is to use eval(), when I print the contents of the cell using my script. This works perfectly when I ran this. I think this is a good solution for me because of my end use, but I will let you experts be the judge. My script is basically a small part of a larger game script (for personal use only) where my script will be accessing random cells from my csv file to feed to the user/player. I don't plan to share my script or my csv file. Hopefully, I am safe using eval in this manner.

Comment: Oh, looks like .replace() also works for me. I was worried that it would not work because I have some cells in my csv file that are strings with format specifiers (% x) but some cells are just straight strings with no format specifiers. However, .replace() seems to have no impact on the cells that have no format specifier. I guess this is the better solution to my issue.

Comment: Henrik, do I actually need csvfile.close() in the script above? I believe the with-as statement should actually automatically close the csv for me. Is there any harm in closing a document twice? I do realize that leaving a document open is bad form and can uses up the number of allowed documents open. Thanks for your help!

Comment: **You do not need it.** Nothing should happen by trying to close a file twice. The reason it survived into the answer was simply me focusing only on getting your code to work. http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using eval :

```
from csv import *

x = "gorillas"

with open('csv_test.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    spamreader = reader(csvfile, quoting = QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    list = []
    for row in spamreader:
        list.append(eval(row[0]))

    print list[1]   

csvfile.close()
```

Comment: `eval()` is dangerous and should _never_ be used with untrusted data.

Comment: Thanks Sachin. eval() does work and would probably be ok for my case, but I think .replace() is a safer implementation as some others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues I saw when running the code -

1. You are not setting the quoting to `QUOTE_NONE` in your `reader` which causes the csv reader to not replace the double double quotes (atleast it didn't in my machine) , with QUOTE_MINIMAL (in my machine , both python 3.4 and python 2.7) it was replacing the double quotes complete and in the `list` there was no double quotes.
2. When printing the strings, you have to evaluate the expression and print it = using `eval()` function.

The code would look something like -

```
>>> with open('csv_test.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = reader(csvfile, quoting = QUOTE_NONE)
...     list = []
...     for row in spamreader:
...         list.append(row[0])
... 
>>> print(eval(list[1]))
I heart gorillas
```

I am just using `|` since it does not occur in your csv example, you can use anything.

Please note its not good practice to keep such statements in a csv and then evaluating them in your function using `eval` because they can write anything into the csv, and can cause potential issues for your program.

Comment: Thanks Anand. eval() does work and would probably be ok for my case, but I think .replace() is a safer implementation as some others have pointed out. Also, quoting = QUOTE_NONE adds extra " " around my string. I did try this before trying QUOTE_MINIMAL.